# Disable arrow keys for number input using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, spinner

I want to disable the up and down keys for a number input through angularjs directive (or otherwise).
**Note:** I don't want to change the input type to text as I have been asked not to.
I already removed the spinners too. 
I am new to angular so don't know much about it. I googled through all the links I could find but they were mostly about hiding the spinners and not about disabling the arrow keys.
I got this code from some other link. This disables the mousewheel for the same. If some changes to this can be done, that will be great.

```
module.directive('input',function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        type: '@'
    },
    link : function (scope, $element) {
        if (scope.type == 'number') {
            $element.on('focus', function () {
                angular.element(this).on('keyup', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            });
            $element.on('blur', function () {

                angular.element(this).off('keyup');
            });
        }
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Please move your question to the body of post.  Please also post what you have tried and/or studied.

Comment: And what should I mention in the question title then?

Comment: Perhaps "Disable the up and down keys for a number input using angularjs".  In the body of your question, you can then be as descriptive as necessary to get the information over to a potential responder.

Comment: I've rarely seen questions with the body visually shorter than the title. You should consider giving **examples** or wait for people to vote down or close your question

Comment: I have made some changes. Please let me know if I need to make more.

Comment: I know this is an older question, but I came across it 5 years later, so other may, too. I think the actual ask here make the number input less **accessible** for users that only navigate through pages with the keyboard. You should weigh that inaccessibility against whatever reasons you have for trying to do something like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to disable up/down arrow keys globally for all input[number] elements:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function(event) {
  var target = event.srcElement || event.target;
  var tag = target.tagName.toUpperCase();
  var type = target.type.toUpperCase();
  if (tag === 'INPUT' && type === 'NUMBER' && 
     (event.keyCode === 38 || event.keyCode === 40)) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

---

Or you can bind it to a single element with a directive:

```
.directive('disableArrows', function() {

  function disableArrows(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 38 || event.keyCode === 40) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }

  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.on('keydown', disableArrows);
    }
  };  
});
```

template:

```
 <input type="number" disable-arrows />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works globally. But I want to restrict it to only some inputs. Can that be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can change your directive to:

```
module.directive('input',function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        type: '@'
    },
    link : function (scope, $element) {
        if (scope.type == 'number') {
            $element.on('focus', function () {
                angular.element(this).on('keyup', function (e) {
                    if (event.keyCode === 38 || event.keyCode === 40) {
                       e.preventDefault();
                    }
                });
            });
            $element.on('blur', function () {

                angular.element(this).off('keyup');
            });
        }
    }
}
});
```